# .NET Core: how to add in-memory object into configuration (Options pattern)

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have in-memory object like:

```
public interface IWaitOptions
{
    Wait Value { get; set; }
}

public class WaitOptions : IWaitOptions
{
    public const string Wait = "Wait";
    public WaitOptions()
    {

    }
    public Wait Value { get; set; }
}

public enum Wait
{
    NoWait = 0,
    Wait = 1
}
```

And I want to put this object via DI in class like:

```
services.AddSingleton<IService,SomeService>();
```

And `SomeService` has IWaitOptions parameter in constructor:

```
 public SomeService(IWaitOptions waitOptions) {}
```

I want to use `Configure`, but dont know how. It should be like:

```
services.Configure<IWaitOptions>(Configuration.GetSection(WaitOptions.Wait));
```

But, `Configuration.GetSection` should get not from appsettings, but from in-memory object:

```
var wait = new WaitOptions() {Value=Wait};
```

So, it should be like:

```
 var wait = new WaitOptions() {Value=Wait};
 services.Configure<IWaitOptions>(Configuration.GetSection(WaitOptions.Wait)); 
 services.AddSingleton<IService,SomeService>();
```

I read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#memory-configuration-provider), but do not know how to implement this.

Comment: When you use `services.Configure<>`, you should consume the options like `public SomeService(IOptions<WaitOptions> waitOptions)`. You can directly set the value with your Configure<> call, and don't need to involve the Configuration at all. [Further reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: As I can see you mixed two different things. `AddInMemoryCollection` registers an in-memory configuration provider. So the `configuration.GetSection` will iterate through not just the `appsettings.json` file but also on the provided dictionary as well.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options). This pattern helps you to access the configuration data in a structured and type-safe way. You can get an `IOption<T>` instance via ctor or you can combine the `GetSection` call with `Get<IOption<T>>` like this: `configuration.GetSection(....).Get<XYZOptions>()`

Comment: @InDieTasten, like this?  services.Configure<IWaitOptions>(opt => { opt.Value = waitOptions.Value.Value; });   ?

Comment: Just register your config object like this: services.AddSingleton<IWaitOptions>(new WaitOptions {  ... });